# One id have two dynamically numbers _ separated. update only one using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some input text fields and I assigning id "parent_number and row_number" dynamically with jQuery to it when press button of addMore.

```
<input type="text" name="xpath" id="xpath_chield_'+parent_number+'_'+row_number+'" size="50"/>
```

it's out put in browser is

```
<input id="xpath_chield_2_3" type="text" size="50" name="xpath">
```

This works fine

After deleting one input field I want to update only "parent_number" to -1 from current parent_number of id but not "row_number"

After update it will output in browser will

```
<input id="xpath_chield_1_3" type="text" size="50" name="xpath">
```

How can I do it with jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce that portion of the ID like this:

```
element.id = element.id.replace( /(\d+)_(\d+)/, function(match, n, o ){
  return ( parseInt( n, 10 ) - 1 ) + "_" + o ;
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ifivor/edit#javascript (Console output)